# c# dataGridView to SQL (insert)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am trying to insert data from datGridView to SQL Server (I load data from an Excel file). But I get a primary key error, that it shouldn't be null.

And if I use something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1012);
```

it returns a duplicate key error...

This is my code:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int stCol = dataGWseznam.Columns.Count;
        string[] poljeNaslovov = new string[dataGWseznam.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < stCol; i++)
        {
            poljeNaslovov[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGWseznam.Columns[i].HeaderText);

        }

        string[] poljeNaslovovAfna = new string[dataGWseznam.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < stCol; i++)
        {
            poljeNaslovovAfna[i] ="@" + Convert.ToString(dataGWseznam.Columns[i].HeaderText);

        }

        string msg1 = String.Join(",", poljeNaslovov.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
        string msg2 = String.Join(",", poljeNaslovovAfna.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));

        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGWseznam.Rows)
            {
                string constring = @"MY DATA SOURCE";

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Monitoring(id,date,time) VALUES(@id,@date,@time)", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1012);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", row.Cells["date"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", row.Cells["time"].Value);

                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done.");
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you use the same id for all rows cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1012);
 You have to implement somthing to allcate diffrent primarykey

Answer (score 0):

The first problem happens because apparently, you did not set the primary key (it is not set as IDENTITY on your table).

Check this to see how to configure your table to automatically increment the ID: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.120).aspx

The "second" error happens because an ID must be unique on your table. So, you'd best make ID an identity field.

(I would recommend you creating a new column on your table, and drop the current one. You can find how to do it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql)

After this maintenance on your table, you should remove this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1012)
```

and change your insert statement from this:

```
INSERT INTO Monitoring(id,date,time) VALUES(@id,@date,@time)
```

to this:

```
INSERT INTO Monitoring(date,time) VALUES(@date,@time)
```

Because since your id column will be an identity, you won't need to supply it, because it will automatically provide the increment for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, thank you that fixed tha tproblem, but now i get this:
The parameterized query '(@date nvarchar(4000),@time nvarchar(4000)' expects the parameter '@date', which was not supplied
but the data is added to the database....

Comment: Was every data recorded? I mean, perhaps the value supplied on the date  variable was empty. In this case you should convert it to the appropriated types.

Comment: Yes all of it, its basically just the error message, i could remove the messagebox from the exception but that would just be hiding the bug...

Comment: I agree with you @mheonyae! We cannot afford to hide bugs. btw, I saw it is all varchar(4000)... nevermind. This error usually happens when the value you supply on the addwithvalue is null. That's why I asked you if every data was recorded. Because if you have an null item on your loop, it may give this error. When you debug your application, you should monitor what is filled on row.Cells["date"].Value; Maybe you could check if the values are null, or default it to some value.

Comment: Also, I would recommend this further read for you, it may improve your next applications: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: i checked and its all values from the datagridview, exactly the same as its expected to be

Comment: @mheonyae I assume your datagridview has the property AllowUserToAddRows = true; correct? This will always create an empty row on your grid. You could check on the datagridviewrow if the property IsNewRow = true. If it is, probably it is the one who is generating this behavior.